# Huge Memory Leaks NSData

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Im working on a music streaming application. Im currently receiving signs of huge memory leaks. Instruments says its related to the code below. There are some blocks of memory being allocated during the while loop. I have ARC turned on. I have exhausted all options and need some more ideas

```
NSData * ringBufferReadData = [NSData dataWithBytes:readPointer length:allBytesAvailable];
// NSLog(@"READER: THESE ARE THE BYTES WE ARE ABOUT TO READ FROM RING BUFFER %lu ",allBytesAvailable);

[ringBuffer didReadLength:allBytesAvailable];

UInt32 ringBufferReadDataOffset = 0;

while (ringBufferReadDataOffset < allBytesAvailable) {

    int packetBytesFilled = [[ringBufferReadData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(12 + ringBufferReadDataOffset, 4)] pm_int32AtOffset:0];

    int packetDescriptionsBytesFilled = [[ringBufferReadData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(16 + ringBufferReadDataOffset, 4)] pm_int32AtOffset:0];

    int offset = AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + ringBufferReadDataOffset;
    NSData* audioBufferData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(char *)([ringBufferReadData bytes] + offset) length:packetBytesFilled];

    offset += packetBytesFilled ;
    NSData *packetDescriptionsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(char *)([ringBufferReadData bytes] + offset) length:packetDescriptionsBytesFilled];

    UInt32 inNumberPackets = packetDescriptionsBytesFilled/AUDIO_STREAM_PACK_DESC_SIZE;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions;

    inPacketDescriptions = [self populatePacketDescriptionArray:packetDescriptionsData
                                        packetDescriptionNumber:inNumberPackets];

    if (inPacketDescriptions[0].mDataByteSize > 65536)
    {
        NSLog(@"packet description size is abnormally large.. soething is wrong");
    }

    [self handleAudioPackets:[audioBufferData bytes]
                 numberBytes:packetBytesFilled
               numberPackets:inNumberPackets
          packetDescriptions:inPacketDescriptions];

    ringBufferReadDataOffset += AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + packetBytesFilled + packetDescriptionsBytesFilled;

    free(inPacketDescriptions);
}
```

Comment: Have you gone over it with the Static Analyzer? Click and hold "Run" and select "Analyze" instead. This should be able to pick up where any leaks are happening.

Comment: Also, where is the end of the while loop?

Comment: while loop starts 5 lines down and ends where the code cuts off

Comment: Ah, there is no close bracket to it so it isn't obvious.

Comment: Please strip away lines that don't affect the problem; we shouldn't have to wade through non-essential stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re creating an awful lot of temporary objects in that loop; if some of them end up in an autorelease pool rather than being explicitly `-release`d, they’re going to accumulate because you don’t have an `@autoreleasepool` inside your loop.  That isn’t, strictly speaking, a memory leak per se (since it will be released eventually), but it might look like one in Instruments.

Try rewriting your loop a bit, removing some of the unnecessary `NSData` objects. e.g.:

```
[ringBuffer didReadLength:allBytesAvailable];

const uint8_t *ptr = readPointer;
const uint8_t *end = ptr + allBytesAvailable;

while (end - ptr >= AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE) {
    // Might be better if you had a struct type; also, you may need to byte swap?
    uint32_t packetBytesFilled = *(uint32_t *)(ptr + 12);
    uint32_t packetDescriptionsBytesFilled = *(uint32_t *)(ptr + 16);

    ptr += AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE;

    // Should check for buffer overrun here
    if (end - ptr < packetBytesFilled)
        break;

    const uint8_t *audioData = ptr;

    ptr += packetBytesFilled;

    // Check for overrun here too (combining the two checks is tricky for 32-bit pointers)
    if (end - ptr < packetDescriptionsBytesFilled)
        break;

    /* Could get rid of this one too if -populatePacketDescriptionArray took a byte pointer;
       at the very least, if you know that this NSData is never retained, you could change to
       using +dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: to avoid unnecessary data copying */
    NSData *packetDescriptionsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:ptr length:packetDescriptionsBytesFilled];

    UInt32 inNumberPackets = packetDescriptionsBytesFilled/AUDIO_STREAM_PACK_DESC_SIZE;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions;

    inPacketDescriptions = [self populatePacketDescriptionArray:packetDescriptionsData
                                        packetDescriptionNumber:inNumberPackets];

    if (inPacketDescriptions[0].mDataByteSize > 65536)
    {
        NSLog(@"packet description size is abnormally large.. soething is wrong");
    }

    // Assuming no exceptions here otherwise you need @try{}...@finally{} to call free()
    [self handleAudioPackets:audioData
                 numberBytes:packetBytesFilled
               numberPackets:inNumberPackets
          packetDescriptions:inPacketDescriptions];

    ptr += packetDescriptionsBytesFilled;

    free(inPacketDescriptions);
}
```

Once you’ve got rid of the extra `NSData` objects, there’s very little memory related activity visible directly within your loop, so the only places you could leak are inside `-populatePacketDescriptionArray:packetDescriptionNumber:` and in `-handleAudioPackets:numberBytes:numberPackets:packetDescriptions:]`.  Or, as it says in the comment I added, if `-handleAudioPackets:numberBytes:numberPackets:packetDescriptions:` were to throw an exception (in which case you’ll leak the memory for `inPacketDescriptions` because there’s no `@try` around that part).